# Best way to auto-update customer SQL Server Express databases

Tags: sql-server, service, sql-update, powerbuilder

We have about 200 customers and the semi-manual remote sql update for every new version has become taxing.

I want you guys to help me find a better solution. A real automatic update of the databases.

Let me describe you the scenario.

Each customer has a server that runs SQL Server Express 2005 or 2008 which is not accessible to them and client PCs with our application (written in PowerBuilder).

Every night, in a client PC that runs our application, they perform a "close day" operation so that all the daily statistics to become permanent and have the application into the new date.

Preferably I would like, when this operation finishes, to launch e.g a service in the server PC that can check the version and if needed to download SQL files and execute them via OSQL.

The hard part for me is how I can trigger a service (or whatever) from a client PC to the server when the "close day" operation finishes. OSQL can run only from the server. I have no way to install it in a thousand client PCs.

Then I can take it from there since I know how to handle OSQL calls etc.

Every help appreciated.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Cant you bind it with time? If day close is done at certain time?

Comment: Unfortunately it is on the customer what time he/she will perform the "close day" operation :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you set up a scheduled job on the server to check the contents of a control file for a certain entry and then fire off the process once it finds it?  If so then have the client application write to the control file once its 'close day' is complete.